# How to start new Activity or refresh current Activity using viewpager

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have viewpager which is in fragment. I am looking to start a new activity or refresh the current activity using tabs on it

For now , I'm using  this to open Fragment called "Sunday" and "Monday" But I would Like to add another tab and when user select this tab either refresh the current activity as same state when app is first opened or open new activity

[image]

Here is my code

```html
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    //RSS link


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        Toolbar myToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(myToolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);

        ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
         adapter.addFragment(new sectionB(), "SEC B");


        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

        TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

        tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

                //here yourDesiredPositionNumber is a int...like 0,1,2,3..according you

                if (tab.getPosition() == 0) {

  Intent i1 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SagarActivity.class);
            startActivity(i1);
                    //here you can do your refresh of start new activity

                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }
        });


    }


    class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
        private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

        public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
            super(manager);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return mFragmentList.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mFragmentList.size();
        }

        public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
            mFragmentList.add(fragment);
            mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
        }
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

**For Refresh**

If you want to refresh whole activity you can call `recreate()` method of activity

in your case you are in a fragment so you need to get activity first so you can do like `getActivity().recreate()`

**For start new activity**

for open a new activity you can use `startActivity()`

i your case you can do Like this

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(),activity_you_want_to_start.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

> Remember one more thing, always make user getActivity() not returning
>   null

**Now in your case**

you need to setup listener on your TabLayout like this then call above method

```
TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.tabs_dayscount);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

 //setting listener on tabLAyout

tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

               //here yourDesiredPositionNumber is a int...like 0,1,2,3..according you

                if (tab.getPosition() == yourDesiredPositionNumber) {


                    //here you can do your refresh of start new activity 

                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }
        });
```

**One Another Way is**

You can also set Listener on ViewPager like this

```
TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.tabs_dayscount);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

 viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {

            //here yourDesiredPositionNumber is a int...like 0,1,2,3..according you

                if(position==yourDesiredPositionNumber){

                //here you can do your refresh of start new activity

                }

                    super.onPageSelected(position);
            }
        });
```

Comment: But where should I write this code , since for now I have two tab button with this code adapter.addFragment(new Sunday(), "Sunday")  ..where should I add this code such that on click of any of these say first tab will open new activity?

Comment: on your tabLayout you can set a listener..you know how to do that or want help in this as well? i can rewrite my answer  but tell me if you know or not..i'll answer accordingly @BirNepali

Comment: yes I do...I sucessfully use the code from one of tutorial and it worked pretty well..but now I need to add one or two more tabs either to refresh or open new activity after those two tabs which opens fragment.

Comment: I have updated my code in question..now even previously visible two tabs are also gone  and there is no any tabs either..now how to make tab visible now then?

Comment: Your question is irrelevant then what you want.. You asked about refreshing and starting activity that's what this snippet doing.. You not implementing things correctly @BirNepali

Comment: Ok  here I have implemented codes i.e adapter.addFragment(new sectionA(), "Section A"); which opens fragment called sectionA but I   would like to open a new activity instead of fragment when tab is clicked. So can you help me with this?